# bandwidth speed test web app in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to write an bandwidth speed test web app program.I used this method to test but it's only work perfectly fine for local host.Whene i upload my project to a web server,it doesn't work and give me access path denied because it tries to download and save the file on the webserver.I want to save this file on client machine.how can i fix this problem ?

```
    public ActionResult download()
    {

        Uri URL = new Uri("http://mylink/myfile.pdf");
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        double starttime = Environment.TickCount;
        wc.DownloadFile(URL, @"C:\speedtest.pdf");
        double endtime = Environment.TickCount;
        double secs = Math.Floor(endtime - starttime) / 1000;
        double secs2 = Math.Round(secs, 0);
        double kbsec = Math.Round(1024 / secs);
        test t = new test();
        try
        {
            System.IO.File.Delete("@C:\\speedtest.pdf");
            t.kbps = kbsec;
            t.message = "Done";
            t.rTime = secs2;
            t.time = secs;

        }
        catch
        {

            t.kbps = kbsec;
            t.message = "File not deleted";
            t.rTime = secs2;
            t.time = secs;
        }

        return Json(t);
    }
```

Comment: Of course it's downloading it on the server-side. Anything that's happening in your controller is happening on the web server. If you want to have it download the file on the client side, you'll need to write some client-side (e.g. JavaScript) code that handles it.

Comment: Can you guide me that how can i do this with java script ?

Comment: I would suggest looking at Visual Studio's 'Web Performance and Load Test' project template. I don't remember which version it comes with, but you might need Ultimate or Test Professional.

Comment: @paradise_human I'd recommend Google. If you have specific questions, post a new question here.

Comment: If you could just write to any user's hard disk at will that would be deeply unsecure.

Comment: If i want to do this in server side how can i do this?I mean how can i get rid of access denied path error in server side and run the exact code that i wrote above ?

Answer (score 1):

wc.DownloadFile(URL, @"C:\speedtest.pdf");

ViewBag URL = speedtest.pdf;

send this file to view and then make the option to download these file

click to download

Comment: You can use tilde wrappers to `add code formatting` to your answer. Three tildes and "C#" will format it multiline for C#.